# iOs receivedData from NSURLConnection is nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I was wondering if anyone could point out why I'm not able to capture a web reply. My `NSLog` shows that my `[NSMutableData receivedData]` has a length of 0 the entire run of the connection. The script that I hit when I click my login button returns a string. My `NSLog` result is pasted below, and after that I've pasted both the .h and .m files that I have.

**NSLog Result**

```
2012-11-28 23:35:22.083 [12548:c07] Clicked on button_login
2012-11-28 23:35:22.090 [12548:c07] theConnection is succesful
2012-11-28 23:35:22.289 [12548:c07] didReceiveResponse
2012-11-28 23:35:22.290 [12548:c07] didReceiveData
2012-11-28 23:35:22.290 [12548:c07] 0
2012-11-28 23:35:22.290 [12548:c07] connectionDidFinishLoading
2012-11-28 23:35:22.290 [12548:c07] 0
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// Create an Action for the button.
- (IBAction)button_login:(id)sender;

// Add property declaration.
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSMutableData *receivedData;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import ViewController.h

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize receivedData;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");    
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {    
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");    
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"%d",[receivedData length]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {    
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"%d",[receivedData length]);
}

- (IBAction)button_login:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Clicked on button_login");    
    NSString *loginScriptURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/app/scripts/login.php?"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginScriptURL]];

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&paramUsername=user&paramPassword=pass"];
    NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Create the actual connection using the request.
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    // Capture the response
    if (theConnection) {        
        NSLog(@"theConnection is succesful");        
    } else {        
        NSLog(@"theConnection failed");
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are not initializing the `receivedData` instance. Just change your property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
```

And change the methods like:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");    
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{    
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");    
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"%d",[receivedData length]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{    
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"%d",[receivedData length]);
}

- (IBAction)button_login:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Clicked on button_login");    
    NSString *loginScriptURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/app/scripts/login.php?"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginScriptURL]];

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&paramUsername=user&paramPassword=pass"];
    NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Create the actual connection using the request.
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    // Capture the response
    if (theConnection)
    {        
        NSLog(@"theConnection is succesful");  
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];      
    } else
    {        
        NSLog(@"theConnection failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: ..... I've been Googling around and trying different things for the past two nights. It took me 30 seconds to apply your corrections and now it's returning a length. Thank you very much.

Comment: P.S. - I think I need some reading material not on the internet (i.e. a book). There's a lot I need to study.

Comment: @yhl: thanks for your comment, this is a nice tutorial site it'll help you http://www.raywenderlich.com/ Also http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-iPhone-and-iPad-Database-Application-Programming.productCd-1118003179.html is a nice book for beginners. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

Please try "%i" instead of %d in nslog

Comment: why...i instead of d .. , You try d instead of i..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try  the following code May be help you.

```
- (IBAction)button_login:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Clicked on button_login");  
            NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dictionnary setObject:@"user"  forKey:@"Username"];
            [dictionnary setObject:@"pass" forKey:@"Password"];

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                               options:kNilOptions
                                                                 error:&error];   

            NSString *urlString = @"Sample URL";

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
            NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
            NSError *requestError = NULL;
            NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
             NSLog(@"%@", responseString); 

}
```

if it is a GET Request then, can you try link : **/login.php?username=admin&password=1212‌​3**

```
- (IBAction)button_login:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Clicked on button_login");  
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/login.php?username=adm‌​in&password=1212‌​3"]];

     // Perform request and get JSON as a NSData object


    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
     NSLog(@"response=%@",response ); 

}
```

and use this code.